# How to make a Java array List with different ints and arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I know this may sound very silly but this is my problem.

I want a **`List`** of people. Where each person has following information about them.

1. Number of fingers they have (int)
2. Ward numbers they have been so far (it's a list of ints),
3. Number of days they have been admitted in hospital (int)

I have no idea what to do here. I know how to make `2d array list of ints` but the problem is that list of ward number messes everything up.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Create a **`Person`** bean class

```
public class Person {
  private int fingers;
  private int days;
  private List<Integer> wardNumbers;
  //getter setters

}
```

And create a **`List<Person> patientList= new ArrayList<Person>`**

So you can store the details as person wise. Or

Create a **`Map<String,Person> patientMap = new HashMap<String,Person>`**
So you can get the person wise details by `patientMap.get("personName");`

**Update(doesn't recommend) for your restriction(as per comment) :**

```
/**All information**/
List<Object> personInfo = new ArrayList<Object>();

/**Ward Number**/
List<Integer> wardNum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
wardNum.add(25);
wardNum.add(55);

personInfo.add(5);  //days
personInfo.add(6);  //fingers

personInfo.add(wardNum); //ward number

Map<String,List<Object>> patientMap = new HashMap<String,List<Object>>();
//Store
patientMap.put("patient1", personInfo);

//Retrieve
System.out.println(patientMap.get("patient1").get(0));//days
System.out.println(patientMap.get("patient1").get(1));//fingers
System.out.println(patientMap.get("patient1").get(2));//Ward Number
```

Comment: any other way to do it? I can't make another class. (there is a restriction)

Comment: Ohh...List of People in your question..what that people refers to?? bean class?? or Show some code what you have done..will try to modify there itself

Comment: Sorry, new to java. But list of people is basically data. Not an object

Comment: @HumparDumpar to avoid the mismatches it's better to have person wise bean class...ok show some code what you have done?

Comment: Frankly, if your teacher is saying you can't make another class, they are setting you up for failure later.  I genuinely cannot recall the last time I even *considered* a 2D array.  They are simply that seldomly used in industry, and definitely not in this way.

Comment: @HumparDumpar check the update..which really i  won't recommend